# Data.MemoCombinators, where can I find examples?

Tags: haskell, recursion, dynamic-programming

This package has some functions to turn recursive functions into dynamic programming recursive functions, for better performance:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-memocombinators/0.3/doc/html/Data-MemoCombinators.html#t:Memo

Unfortunately, they only have an example for the simplest type of function, and there are no examples on how to use a function of 2 variables. Where can I find an example of how to, for example, turn `[Int] -> Int -> Int` function into a dynamic-programming function? The documentation says memo2 takes two `Memo`s as first arguments, but I'm not sure what that means.

**Solution:**

As Hammar described, instead of defining a function as:

```
foo :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
foo list value = ...
```

to use memo2:

```
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

foo = Memo.memo2 (Memo.list Memo.integral) Memo.integral foo'
  where ... (define foo' with recursive calls to foo.)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The library defines the type `Memo a`, which is a "memoizer" for functions taking arguments of type `a`. The key to understanding how to use this library is to understand how to use and compose these memoizers.

In the simple case, you have a single argument function and a simple memoizer, for example a Fibonacci function and a memoizer for `Integral` arguments. In such a case, we obtain the memoized function by applying the memoizer to the function to be memoized:

```
 fib = Memo.integral fib'
   where
     fib' 0 = 0
     fib' 1 = 1
     fib' x = fib (x-1) + fib (x-2)
```

Some memoizers take arguments to customize their behavior, for example `arrayRange`. In the following example, `fib n` will only be memoized if `n` is between 1 and 100.

```
fib = Memo.arrayRange (1, 100) fib'
  where ...
```

The library also provides combinators for building more complex memoizers out of simple ones. For example, `list`, which turns a memoizer for `a` into a memoizer for `[a]`.

Finally, to memoize functions of multiple arguments there are the functions `memo2` and `memo3`, which take a memoizer for each argument plus a function and returns a memoized function.

So to memoize your two-argument function, we will need to use `memo2`. We can use the `integral` memoizer for the `Int` argument, and for the `[Int]` argument we can use `list integral`. Putting this together, we get something like this:

```
memo2 (list integral) integral foo
```

However, you can also use more specific memoizers if you know the numbers are in some specified range. For example, if the numbers in the list are between 1 and 10 and the second argument is between 15 and 20:

```
memo2 (list $ arrayRange (1, 10)) (arrayRange (15, 20)) foo
```

Whether this makes sense or not, depends on your application.

Answer (score 2):

Per types and documentation, I believe

```
foo :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
```

should be memoised per

```
memo2 (list integral) integral foo
```

(disclaimer: I haven't used data-memocombinators).

Comment: It says "not in scope" for list and integral.

Comment: @NoBugs: Are you importing `Data.MemoCombinators` qualified? If so, you'll have to include the module prefix (e.g. `Memo.memo2`), or just change it to a regular import.

Comment: Strange. They appear in the docs and export list of 0.3 as well as 0.4.2 and 0.2, the only version without them is 0.1. Is it accidentally that version which you have installed?

Comment: I downloaded from that site, which links 0.3. Changing integral to Memo.integral doesn't fix it though.

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg list data-memocombinators` spit out? Anyway, can we see the full source?